# Clustering: Cluster validation

Tags: testing, cluster-analysis, linear-algebra

I want to use some clustering method for large social network dataset. The problem is how to evaluate the clustering method. yes, I can use some external ,internal and relative cluster validation methods. I used Normalized mutual information(NMI) as external validation method for cluster validation based on synthetic data. I produced some synthetic dataset by producing 5 clusters with equal number of nodes and some strongly connected links inside each cluster and weak links between clusters to check the clustering method, Then I analysed the spectral clustering and modularity based community detection methods on this synthetic datasets. I use the clustering with the best NMI for my real world dataset and check the error(cost function) of my algorithm and the result was good. Is my testing method for my cost function is good? or I should also validate clusters of my real word clusters again?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try more than one measure.

There are a dozen cluster validation measures, and it's hard to predict which one is most appropriate for a problem. The differences between them are not really understood yet, so it's best if you consult more than one.

Also note that if you don't use a normalized measure, the baseline may be really high. So the measures are mostly useful to say "result A is more similar to result B than result C", but should not be taken as an absolute measure of quality. They are a relative measure of similarity.

Comment: @AnonyMousse Thanks for answer. I'm so sorry for being so late in replying to your answer. The problem is how to merge and conclude from different indexes(internal for real world data with unknown clustering structure)

Comment: Don't try to break down everything into a single number. Shoe size and eye color are also two different things that just can't be combined into a single number reasonably.

Comment: @AnonyMousse Thanks for comment. I am agree with you :). But I need just one clustering number that has good result for all indexes. So, how to find the point with different indexes? Do you have any idea?

Comment: I do not understand your sentence. There are infinite ways to reduce the results to a single number, but I'm not aware of a single mathematical reason to prefer one over using constant "0".

Comment: @AnonyMousse Thanks, as you know structure of real dataset is unknown and clustering methods like spectral clustering and kmeans take number of clusters as an input. I can use internal indexes in different number of clusters to find the good clustering number. So I have one plot for each index(x axes for index and y axes for number of cluster or other parameter) I want to merge plots from different indexes and find one good number of clusters.I use multiplication of plots to find the optimum point of all but I don't know if the result is ok or not.Can you explain your answer in more details?

Comment: Internal indexes just measure another statistical property. This does not at all imply that the result is any better by usefulness. Usefulness cannot be captured mathematically. So **try out** different clustering results, **which actually is better**, not just which scores higher on some index. High index values can still be useless. And in fact with k-means, when it is used for discretization purposes, a "too large" k will usually work at least as good.

Comment: Thanks for good comment. Do I understand what you mean?Do you mean to check my cost function in real problem after clustering? but I also want to compare different clustering method for real problem and how to prove for my supervisor :) or anyone that the results is good index make it more explainable. Do you agree with me? I ask my question also in  [mathematics site](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/476328/cluster-validation-and-determining-number-of-clusters).Do you have more suggestion? Thanks a lot for your patience :).

Comment: My features data is so sparse and there are many features for spectral clustering. May it cause problem?  Do the [results](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/476328/cluster-validation-and-determining-number-of-clusters) that I obtained are natural?

Comment: Don't look at the numbers. **Evaluate the actual clusters**, manually. Are the obtained clusters *useful*? Can you interpret them? Any clustering, even if it scores really high, can be useless.